# Segmentation fault when free the linked list node

Tags: c++, pointers, null, segmentation-fault, free

```
LNode * deleteNext (LNode *L) {
  if (L == NULL) { return L; }

  LNode *deleted = L->next;
  L->next = L->next->next;
  //L->next->next = NULL;

  delete deleted;
  return L->next;
}
```

This is a function to delete the next node of pointed node, simple logic. The current code works fine. But if I uncomment the commented line, there will be a segmentation-fault, which seems weird to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you call the function? (what do you pass as L?)

Comment: you check for if L is NULL, but you dont check for L->next or L->next->next if NULLs.

Comment: @Vladp Glad you asked, the prams could be all the nodes in the linked list **except** the tail node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a wrong implementation. What if `L->next` is NULL?

Here is one possible (correct) implementation:

```
LNode * deleteNext (LNode *L) 
{
  if (L == NULL || L->next == NULL) return NULL;

  LNode *deleted = L->next; //L->next is NOT NULL
  L->next = L->next->next;  
          //^^^^^^^^^^^^ could be NULL though

  delete deleted;
  return L->next; //L->next could be NULL here
}
```

Now it is up to you what you want to return from the function. You could return `L` instead of `L->next`, or you could return `std::pair<LNode*, bool>` containing `L` and a boolean value indicating whether delete is done or not.

Comment: what if `L->next->next` NULL?

Comment: @FredrickGauss: In that case, the function returns `NULL` (i.e `L->next` at `return` would be `NULL`).

Comment: Thank you two. Sorry for not mentioning about the input. Actually the input could always be right, I mean, there is no circumstance that L->next is NULL. L->next->next could be NULL unless it is the tail node whose next will always be NULL, so it's safe then.

Comment: @BrianYang: It is still the function responsibility for bad inputs. So the function must check for `L->next==NULL`.

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks, got that. Based on my logic for this function, it shouldn't be wrong. I mean, for that commented line.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how your list's head and tail are implemented. I will assume the last element of the list has its next link set to null (i.e. the list is not a ring closing on itself).

The call is conceptually wrong. You cannot handle a single-linked list without keeping a reference to its head (first element), unless you use the first element as the head, which is ugly and inefficient.

Also you must decide what to do with the removed element. Deleting it and then returning a pointer to its still warm corpse is at any rate not the best choice.

I will assume the caller might be interrested in retrieving the element (in which case it's the caller that will have to delete it once he's done using it).

```
LNode * removeNext (LNode *L)
{
  if (L == NULL) panic ("Caller gave me a null pointer. What was he thinking?");
  // should panic if the caller passes anything but a valid element pointer,
  // be it NULL or 0x12345678

  LNode * removed = L->next;
  if (removed = NULL) return NULL; // L is the end of list: nothing to remove
  L->next = removed->next; // removed does exist, so its next field is valid

  // delete removed; // use this for the void deleteNext() variant
  return removed;
}
```

This will be unable to empty the list completely. At least a single element will remain stuck in it (the pseudo-head, so to speak).

Also you will have to initialize the list with the said pseudo-head. Calling removeNext with the pseudo-head is safe, it will be equivalent to using the list as a LIFO.
This implementation will not allow an easy use as a FIFO though, since there will be no easy way to maintain a fixed reference to the tail (last element) of the list.

The way I would do it is rather like so:

```
typedef struct _buffer {
   struct _buffer * next;
   unsigned long    data;
   } tBuffer;

typedef struct {
   tBuffer * head;
   } tLIST; 

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   Put a buffer into a list
   --------------------------------------------------------------------- */
static void list_put (tLIST * mbx, tBuffer * msg)
{
   msg->next = mbx->head;
   mbx->head = msg;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   get a buffer from a list
   --------------------------------------------------------------------- */
static tBuffer * list_get (tLIST * mbx)
{
   tBuffer * res;

   /* get first message from the mailbox */
   res = mbx->head;

   if (res != NULL)
      {
      /* unlink the buffer */
      mbx->head = res->next;
      }

   return res;
}
```

*(I wrote this back in the mid-90's. Genuine vintage ANSI C. Ah, those were the days...)*

It boils down to this: if you're going to implement a singly-linked list, don't try to use it like a random access data structure. It's inefficient at best, and more often than not a nest of bugs. A single-linked list can be used as a FIFO or possibly a stack, and that's about it.

std:: templates offer you everything you could dream of in terms of storage structures, and they have been tested and optimized over the last 20 years or so. No man alive (except Donald Knuth maybe) could do better with a design from scratch.

Comment: Very interesting it is. Yoda said.

Comment: Excuse my French, young padawan. English my native language is not ;).